# Which visa type should I be applying for short visit to Oman being an Indian national as a UAE resident

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, oman

I am an Indian national currently at UAE residing here as a resident and am planning to travel to Oman by flight from Abu dhabi,

I checked on their [website](https://www.rop.gov.om/english/visaservices_mainpage.html) but its a bit confusing,

Among the options I could find one relevant to me : ***29A GCC Resident Visa***

Wondering if this is the correct visa I should get for a short visit of 2-3 days !

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Edit : My profession on UAE visa is '**Software Developer**'

Comment: That visa appears to require you work in one of a somewhat restrictive list of professions. In this case, stating what you do may increase the chances of someone being able to help you.

Comment: This appears to be the right list http://beyondtheroute.com/gcc-resident-visit-visa-approved-professions/ but for better odds, see the eligibilty wizard https://evisa.rop.gov.om/visa-eligibility

Comment: Thats why I am confused as this visa which is most relevant to me seems for work and I am just going as a tourist.. Also The visa-eligilibity is what I checked already.. Its not so clear.. 
Now the question should I get this **29A GCC** one as thats what is the most relevant one..

Comment: Timatic indicates you should get an e-visa prior to departure https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true You can also try the IATA website to confirm https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Answer (score 2):

Citizens of India (and many other countries) are [exempt from the need to obtain an Omani visa in advance](https://fm.gov.om/visitors/entry-visas/) for a touristic stay of up to 14 days. You need to have a confirmed hotel booking, return flight, and health insurance which will cover you during your stay.

Comment: I don't think so.. but still I will confirm..

Comment: Why do you think @mlc is incorrect? [The Omani government page referenced on the cited page](https://fm.gov.om/visitors/entry-visas/) specifically lists Indian citizens as eligible for entry and a 14-day stay for tourism without applying for a visa in advance.

Comment: The reason I say @mlc may be incorrect is cuz I tried to get in touch with Indians who have been to Oman by land and they specifically mentioned they had to get a visa which they procured on arrival there while entering and were charged about 80-100 UAE Dhirams. If Indians didn't need a visa and were eligible for entry for upto 14-day stay for tourism then why did the officials charge them for visa. I only received reply from them today and I checked with about 2-3 people who said they needed a visa..

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Thanks. It's certainly possible that the Omani government site is in error, or that Omani Immigration got it wrong at the border. Please report back here — using the "Your Answer" button — to report your actual experience.